# Core Data relationships. Do I need to set relationships between objects

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a question related to Core Data. As I've don't use it for some time, I need some refresher.

I have 2 entities Category and Task. Category can have many Tasks.

So I have 2 api request that returns `categories` and `tasks`

Category has id
Task has id and categoryId

So If I have two such request what I need to do to have them inserted to Core Data and related correctly.

A. Does it suffice to just do
1. insert categories to core date
2. insert task to core data
(can I do NSBatchInsertUpdateRequest?)
Here I assume as Task object has categoryId field the relationship will be created automagically. So when I next request categories each will be pointing to their list of tasks and otherwise each task will point to its category

B. I need to set this relationship manually it

1. Insert categories
2. Insert task and for each task object set category for it like
   `task.category = category`
   so i will need to create this category in place like `Category(context: context)`
   or request this `Category` based on `task.categoryId`

C. Set this relationship on both side like
task.category = category
category.tasks = tasks

Comment: B is the right answer but you can insert Task and Category objects together.

Comment: And why case A doesn't work ? 
entities returned from insertion methods  won't be connected, but on subsequent NSFetchRequest of categories, doesn't it find valid relationships to task as it has in model defined foreign and primary keys ?

Comment: _"will be created automagically"_, because this will never happen, you need to tell core data which tasks belongs to which categories. Forgot about primary and foreign keys when working with Core Data, it's an object mapping framework with persistence support.

Comment: Ok it hase some objectID underneath and I think they relate data together.